# Convert EF Model Property to Navigation Property

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

What are the step to convert/migrate a model property into a navigation property (create a new class and create a foreign key relationship, using EF Code First Migration.

In the example below, I want to convert the Student class property Country into a navigational property, without losing in data.

**Current Model**

```
public class Student
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

**Proposed Model**

```
public class Student
{
     public int ID { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public int CountryID { get; set; }
     public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
}

public class Country 
{
     public int ID { get; set; }            
     public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

**Add-Migration NavigationProperty**

```
public override void Up()
        {
            CreateTable(
                "dbo.Countries",
                c => new
                    {
                        ID = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                        CountryName = c.String(),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.ID);

            AddColumn("dbo.Students", "CountryID", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
            CreateIndex("dbo.Students", "CountryID");
            AddForeignKey("dbo.Students", "CountryID", "dbo.Countries", "ID", cascadeDelete: true);
            DropColumn("dbo.Students", "Country");
        }
```

**Update-Database Error**

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Students_dbo.Countries_CountryID". The conflict occurred in database "aspnet-navprop-20141009041805", table "dbo.Countries", column 'ID'.

Comment: Just run add-migration after making the necessary changes in your code and EF will do the work.

Comment: I get this error message when I update the database: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Students_dbo.Countries_CountryID". The conflict occurred in database "aspnet-navprop-20141009041805", table "dbo.Countries", column 'ID'.

Comment: I believe this is because the added column `CountryID` on table `Students` does not allow nulls and I assume you have data in the `Students` table? Move all data in `Students` table to a temp table then delete them from `Students` table then run update-database again.